# how can I create view at run time in base adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, baseadapter

I don't want to use layout file in `BaseAdapter` . I want to create view in base adapter so I can call this adapter for every `listview`. 
My code doesnt work.

here is my code :

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<PublicObject> objects;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<PublicObject> objects)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.objects.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return this.objects.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    private TextView CreateTextView()
    {
        TextView txtView = new TextView(this.context);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);
        txtView.setGravity(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
        txtView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        txtView.setTextSize(14);
        txtView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        return txtView;
    }

    protected static class ViewHolder
    {
        private List<TextView> viewList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if(convertView == null)
        {
            LinearLayout lnr = new LinearLayout(this.context);
            lnr.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            lnr.setLayoutParams(lp);
            List<TextView> viewList = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i = 0, limit = this.objects.get(0).GetList().size(); i < limit; i++) {
                TextView txt = this.CreateTextView();
                lnr.addView(txt);
                viewList.add(txt);
            }
            convertView = lnr;
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.viewList = viewList;
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        List<TextView> views = viewHolder.viewList;
        List<String> s = this.objects.get(position).GetList();
        for(int i = 0, limit = s.size(); i < limit; i++)
        {
            TextView txt = views.get(i);
            txt.setText(s.get(i));
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

This is my model class,

```
public class PublicObject {
    private List<String> list;

    public PublicObject(List<String> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public List<String> GetList() {
        return this.list;
    }
}
```

Error

9 16:30:23.668 302-302/com.example.deryaaxis.searchviewtempalte E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                      Process: com.example.deryaaxis.searchviewtempalte, PID: 302
                                                                                      java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
                                                                                          at android.widget.ListView.measureScrapChild(ListView.java:1183)
                                                                                          at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1265)
                                                                                          at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
                                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16820)
                                                                                          at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
                                                                                          at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
                                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16820)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5156)
                                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16820)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5156)
                                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:391)
                                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16820)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5156)
                                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16820)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5156)
                                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
                                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
                                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
                                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16820)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5156)
                                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2295)
                                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16820)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1962)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1156)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1341)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1043)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
                                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:771)
                                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
                                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
                                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:757)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610)
                                                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: *I dont want to use layout file in base adapter*, why ? *My code desnt work* what isn't it working ?

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is probably because you are using LayoutParams for Linear Layout for a textView and then putting that textView into your listView.
You should change the LinearLayout.LayoutParams to this

```
txtView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: i tried, it didnt work. i want to create textviews in adapter programmatically. I dont want to use a layout file for adapter.